# Implement different behavior for dismissing UIAlertController action sheet when tapping on view for cancel event

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I am trying to make cancel button work and navigate to the previous screen. I am pressing outside the action sheet and the cancel event is still occurring.

Here is my code:

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "searchEvent", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "event 1", style: .default, handler: nil)

alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "event 2", style: .default, handler: nil)
alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "event 3", style: .default, handler: nil)

alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: {[weak self] (action) in
    self?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}))
```

Comment: This is as expected. Tapping outside of an action sheet is the same as tapping the Cancel button.

Comment: is there anyway I can change that behaviour? like choosing y value in the view controller to dismiss

Comment: It may be a better idea to make canceling (either via the Cancel button or by tapping outside the alert view) _not_ dismiss the VC.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: {
        alertController.view.superview?.subviews[0].isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    })
```

This will disable any behavior for user tapping outside the action sheet

Answer (score 0):

If you want different behavior for tapping cancel and tapping outside of action sheet, former cancels and dismisses VC, later only cancels action sheet, then you need to change your cancel button style to something other than cancel and then add a gesture recognizer to 
 self.actionSheet.view.superview?.subviews.first?

The gesture recognizer block will dismiss the action sheet
The cancel button block will dismiss the view controller.